# I change ec2 server instance type, Afteward my website have not worked

Tags: amazon-ec2, server, dns, instance, amazon-route53

I  did not  use  elastic Ip  address.  I  assigned  my  public  Ip  address change  other ip Adress. After I change  my public address in Route 53 .  but  it  will not work.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. However, it sounds like you stopped and started an Amazon EC2 instance to change the Instance Type. Since you are not using an Elastic IP address, this means that your instance received a different Public IP address. Are you able to access the instance via the Public IP address (without using the domain name), with via HTTP or SSH?

Comment: I can't  access  the  instanve  via Public IP address(without using domain name ) with http and  ssh.

Comment: You should start by trying to obtain SSH access. What is the configuration of the Security Group Inbound rules associated with that instance?

Comment: I  can't  start  by  SSH old  access and new  key pair.  Also  I can't  start by  connect to inctance .  It is  error "There was a problem connecting to your instance
Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, wait a few minutes and try again. Otherwise, ensure the instance is running on an AMI that supports EC2 Instance Connect."

Comment: The OP should try to revise this question or else it will be regarded as vague inline with vague response.

Comment: @quintumnia  I  asked  from  Amazon  Tech suport . but  they did not answer  my question

Comment: @AsliddinNazarov What sometimes affects the response/answers via aws tech support is timezone, and like what I said ,you have to make your issue understandable to get effective feedback quickly.